# Get current page apache tiles within jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp, apache-tiles

I have spring mvc application using apache tiles.Main file is template.jsp which includes header.jsp, then got place for potential messages and footer.jsp included.
Is there a way to check within jsp page ( using JSTL ) on which page I'm inside header.jsp code ?
Normal way of getting page URL are not good because

```
${pageContext.request.servletPath}
```

Always get's me the page I supposed to be so , template:

```
/WEB-INF/tiles/template.jsp
```

Is there a way to do it somehow , without adding anything to model from within spring?

(Because this is one of way to do this )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the page URL (as it would appear in the browser) using the following EL in your JSP:

```
${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.request_uri']}
```